# Angular $broadcast does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I try to broadcast an event:

```
$scope.selectCategory = function(cat) {
    $scope.$broadcast('Cat', {catID: cat});
}
```

it doesn't get caught by `$scope.$on`:

```
$scope.$on('Cat', function (event, args) {
    console.log("in");
    $scope.catid = args.catID;
});
```

Question: I successfully pass the variable into **broadcast** but **$scope.on** callback never gets triggered.

Answer (score 1):

you need to $broadcast on $rootScope:

```
$scope.selectCategory = function(cat) {
                                // $location.path('/films/' + cat);
                                $rootScope.$broadcast('Cat', {catID: cat});
                                console.log(cat);
                            }
```

rest of your code should be fine then.

Ref: [Official Angular Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)